# Mplayer. Почему зависает framebuffer?

Tags: linux

Есть задача крутить видео плайлист на машине с Linux без графики. Использую framebuffer, команда примерно такая mplayer -vo fbdev2 -playlist /home/playlist
Все замечательно играет. Но если послать kill -9 pid или просто с консоли прервать команду mplayer'a через ctrl + c, то экран зависает. То есть показывает изображение последнего кадра видео. Иногда эту ситуацию помогает решить переключение на другую консоль через alt + f(номер консоли). Но иногда помогает только перезагрузка. На клавиатуру экран не реагирует. По ssh все работает. Отсюда вопрос как можно обнулить framebuffer и возобновить изображение с tty. 
Промучившись с этой проблемой, поднял X'ы ( побывал и kde и gnome и lfxe ). Ситуация идентична, но процент полного зависания меньше. То есть чаще всего помогает ctrl + alt +f(номер консоли). 
Решил уже запускать не через framebuffer а через mplayer -vo xv, x11 и т.д. Во всех режимах что завелись есть другой глюк. При смене видео перед тем как начнет играть следующее по плейлисту, на несколько миллисекунд появляется изображение рабочего стола. Подскажите как все это можно решить?
p.s. 
Система Centos 7 64 битный.
Железо Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 847 @ 1.10GHz и 2gb ram.

Comment: насколько мне известно, даже если оставить лишь **один** вопрос про «зависание» в виртуальном терминале, то ответ невозможно свести к «проблема у вас вот в этом и этом». вопрос в нынешней форме подразумевает долгую дискуссию с множеством уточняющих вопросов-ответов, т.е. выпадает из формы, предпочтительной на [ru.so], и вряд ли будет полезен другим людям. задайте, пожалуйста, более конкретный **один** вопрос. а второй, третий, и т.д. вопросы можно задавать с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @syslinux Вам лучше задать этот вопрос на каком-нибудь форуме сисадминов, тут отвечают в основном на энциклопедичные вопросы. PS: лично мне вопрос понятен, но исследованиями для его решения заниматься нет времени и желания.

Comment: @dsnk, вопрос, дейтствительно, вполне понятен, но для **правильного** ответа на него надо задать ещё уйму наводящих вопросов, дать рекомендации по выяснению того, где именно происходит ошибка (если она вообще происходит). т.е., абсолютно вне модели, на которую опирается [so] вообще и [ru.so] в частности.